# Passing a function result to a parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, closures, mongoose

So I have this method for a User object to check for an existing record.

```
User.findOrCreate = function(json){
    User.findOne({'email' : json.email}, function(err, user){
        if (!user){
            user = new User({
                id: json.id,
                email: json.email,
                f_name: json.first_name,
                l_name: json.last_name,
                gender: json.gender,
                locale: json.locale
            });
            user.save(function(err){
                if (err) return handleError(err);
                return user;
            });
        } else {
            return user;
        }
    });
}
```

so basically I want to return the variable "user" to the method findOrCreate, so that I can use it in another place like so:

```
var user = User.findOrCreate(profile._json);
```

But instead, user = undefined when I log it out. Having a lot of trouble with this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Consider the fact that you have created an inner function.

Comment: In node.js, you can't return an asynchronous result from a function, you have to use callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
var user = User.findOrCreate(profile._json);
```

Because the execution of `User.findOne` is async, so when `findOrCreate` returns, probably `User.findOne` wasn't executed yet.

The right way of getting the user value is to use another callback in `findOrCreate`:

```
User.findOrCreate = function(json, callback){
    User.findOne({'email' : json.email}, function(err, user){
       if (!user){
           user = new User({
               id: json.id,
               email: json.email,
               f_name: json.first_name,
               l_name: json.last_name,
               gender: json.gender,
               locale: json.locale
            });
            user.save(function(err){
               if (err) return handleError(err);
               callback(user);
            });
        } else {
            callback(user);
        }
     });
};
```

As you can see handling all of those callbacks can make you mad. If you didn't tried promises yet take a look to the Q library: http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/

It will make your life easy:

```
 var userPromise = User.findOrCreate(profile._json);
 /* then when you need a user */
 userPromise.done(function (user) { /* do something */ });
```

The advantage is that promises comes with very useful abstractions to handle control flow of async code, for example using promises you can write `findOrCreate` like this:

```
  User.findOrCreate = function(json) {
       return User.findOne({email:json.email}).then(createIfNull);
  };
```

Where `createIfNull` is the code that you have inside the `if` block (if `save` also returns a promise things are easy.. if not you can create one and return it, see Q examples... the docs are not very intuitive but once that you get used to it you'll see that it really simplifies all the callback mess).

Answer (score 0):

The `User.getOrCreate` function has not any `return` statement, so of course it will return `undefined`, in fact `findOne` is working async, so your `getOrCreate` function should be async too, So you can change your function definition to:

```
User.findOrCreate = function(json, callback) {
```

and instead of `return user;` you should run the callback function:

```
callback(user);
```